# iframe not inserting by editor role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I am inserting Facebook video iframe in a post, which works fine when i logged in by admin user, but when I login by editor user role, and trying to insert iframe  in a post and click on update button then iframe not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

this question easy to do, you can review the right of user, user, or admin can add facebook iframe ok, [web wordpress](https://www.binhduongmicro.com/thiet-ke-web/) easy to do and install plugin easy to control all